# This method and I need it to be called from angular frontend as a POST. write that function in my angular to call this post method in .net

Tags: .net, angular

This is my method in .net in uploadController:

```html
[Produces("application/json")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ValidationProblemDetails), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status202Accepted)]
        [HttpPost("BulkUpdate")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> BulkUpdate([FromBody] List<PreviewUpload> employees)
        {
            await EmployeeService.BulkUpdateEmployees(employees);

            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status202Accepted);
        }
```

and this is my call method in angular which needs to be completed as I dont think its correct:

```html
 this.http.get('/api/upload/'+this.fileName)
              .subscribe((data: any[]) => {
                console.log(data);
                this.values = data;


              });
            confirmHandler(event: any) {
    console.log("In Conform Handler");
    this.http.post('/api/upload/BulkUpdate',this.values)
      .subscribe();
  }
```

Not sure if line         this.http.post('/api/upload/BulkUpdate',this.values)
is sending this.values theright way as I am getting NULL exception Error in backend.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The question you asked does not have a proper context so I am not sure how much help you can receive. You need to be more specific. If you can create a sample code in stackblitz or something similar that will help others answer you easily.

Now coming to your question I can point you towards a few things that may help you find your issue

When is the event called?

> confirmHandler(event: any)

Have you confirmed whether the event is fired after the get call is complete? As you know the get call is returning the data asynchronously. So it may happen that your event is being called before the get is completed. In that case this.values may be null

Based on the limited info available in your question that is the best I can do. You can update your question to be specific if you need more help. Happy Coding.